# how to convert a string into integer representation and change it back

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, ascii

I was wondering if there were any good methods to change a string into an integer representation and then be able to change the integer representation back to a string?  There are a lot of ways to change a string to an integer representation by changing each character to ASCII, etc. but I was confused by how to change the ascii integer back into the fully formed string.

I am trying to represent my object of 3 strings into an integer so that I do not have to group by 3 string but just 1 integer.

For example an object of :

("hey",
"hello",
"goodbye")

would have an int representation of lets say 123423425 with some algorithm.

Then if possible I would like to be able convert that int from another algorithm back into

("hey",
"hello",
"goodbye")

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: An important note: not every character in a string has a corresponding ASCII code. Another note (related): not every string is ASCII-encoded. And a corresponding reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What if you also explain the original task you're trying to solve? Since your current attempt is "not correct" by definition.

Comment: sorry about that. I added the exact question i am trying to solve

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking because there are waaaaay more collections of strings than there are `int`s. Is there anything special about your “object of 3 strings”? How about telling us [what you're trying to accomplish](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/) instead of what you want to do, because what you want to do can't work. Start with why you think you “have to group by 3 string”.

Comment: @zerkms No .NET string is ASCII-encoded. A .NET String is a counted sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code units, with one or two code units per Unicode codepoint, with one base codepoint and zero or more combining codepoints per Unicode grapheme. For example, a Fraktur lower case U with a combining dot above "\uD835\uDD32\u0307" (̇̇̇̇̇̇). [It might not render in your browser. Well, somehow I got multiple dots, but you get the point.]

Comment: @Tom Blodget: I'm lost: "string is ASCII-encoded" "is a counted sequence of Unicode/UTF-16 code units" --- how both these statements can be true?

Comment: @zerkms I am responding to your comment "not every string is ASCII-encoded." That is true but misleading because there aren't any .NET strings that are ASCII-encoded.

Comment: You say that your `{"hey", "hello", "goodbye"}` is converted to an integer "with some algorithm." In order for us to answer your question, it's critically important to know what "some algorithm" is. If you're asking how to reverse a hash code, by the way, the answer is, "you can't," as @DourHighArch pointed out in his comment.

Comment: ahhaa so you want to represent an array of string just by a number.  we can say you want to assign a ID to that array and then get array using that ID right??

Comment: you want only alphabet(a-z & A-Z) or all the possible char?  I can suggest a way if want only for alphabt

Comment: Thanks for all of the responses guys. Is there a way with only the alphabet characters?

Comment: Is there a way to do what? We still don't know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
int number = Int32.Parse("45");
string formatted = number.ToString()//add formatting if needed
```

You can go back and forth

Reference for format strings: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx

Convert char array to string

```
char[] charArray = {'1', '2', '3'};
String str = String.valueOf(charArray);
```

Comment: Thanks that would work for me if the strings were numbers, but what if the strings were chars. Sorry didn't clearly explain the context in the question

Comment: added a char conversion